# Detect Android Memory Leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, ddms

When i debug my app process in DDMS (with Update Heap selected) on every "Cause GC" all data in columns is stay same as I expect, also when I press Home Button and return to app all data also is same,  but on every app restart (press Back button on phone and then re-open app again) data in "Allocated" columns little increase.

For example: **14 335 MB**, **14 353 MB**, **14 370 MB**, **14 383 MB**.

Is that mean my app has memory leaks ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is that mean my app has memory leaks ?

Conceivably. Use DDMS to generate a heap dump, then use MAT to try to determine if indeed you do have memory leaks.

Here is [a Google Developer Blog post on the subject](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html). Here is [a YouTube video of a Google I|O 2011 presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) by the same author on the same subject.

Comment: thank you. I know about MAT (already read Google Developer Blog before ask question), its already added to Eclipse, but I dont quite understand it. For example which parameter showns me on leak?

Comment: @Sever: I would recommend watching the video.